# setup.py - building c-extension with Numpy dependency

Tags: python, c, numpy, packaging

I have created a simple c-function (using the guide here [Create Numpy ufunc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/c-info.ufunc-tutorial.html)) and I'm now trying to distribute my package on pypi. For it to work, it needs to compile the c-file(s) into a .so -file, which then can be imported from python and everything is good. To compile it needs the header file `numpy/ndarraytypes.h` from Numpy.

When building and installing locally, it works fine. This since I know where the header files are located. However when distributing it, **where can we find the Numpy folder?** It is obvious from the logs that numpy gets installed before my package is built and installed so I just need to include the correct Numpy folder.

```
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools import Extension

if __name__ == "__main__":
    setup(
        name="myPack",
        install_requires=[
            "numpy>=1.22.3", # <- where is this one located after it gets installed?
        ],
        ext_modules=[
            Extension(
                'npufunc',
                sources=['npufunc.c'],
                include_dirs=[
                    # what to put here for it to find the "numpy/ndarraytypes.h" header file when installing?
                    "/usr/local/Cellar/numpy/1.22.3_1/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/include/" # <- this one I have locally and when added, installtion works fine
                ]
            ),
        ]
    )
```

Comment: Please read tag descriptors before using the tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can query `numpy` for the include directory from python via

```py
import numpy
numpy.get_include()
```

This should return a string (`/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/include` on my system) which you can add to the `include_dirs`. See [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.get_include.html) for the docs.

As for you question: `numpy` is a `build dependency` for you project. The old `setup.py` method is kind of bad at handling those, which is why it has been superseded by the more modern `pyproject.toml` [approach](https://peps.python.org/pep-0518/), which (among other things) makes such specifications possible. A fairly minimal `pyproject.toml` for your setting (setuptools + numpy) would look like this:

```ini
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools", "wheel", "oldest-supported-numpy"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
```

Given such a `pyproject.toml` you can build the extension using the python build module by calling

```
python -m build
```

which should produce a wheel with a compiled so inside it.

Comment: But how can I import numpy when it has, at that moment, not yet been installed?